# Custom Cartridge

Tags: odoo, openshift

I want to create a cartridge for OpenERP, i create one for Python 2.6.6, it's work, and i try to modifie the setup to execute "openerp-server" but i dont know where i can put the openERP code ? Where i puting him in the "Template" folder it gives my this error :

> Unable to complete the requested operation due to: The server
>   ex-std-node295.prod.rhcloud.com that your application is running on
>   failed to respond in time. This may be due to a system restart..
>   Reference ID: 377355d1a4f3f9cc0d1914cca77dace9

Also I modified the `/bin/setup` like this :

```
Call openerp-server
exec $OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_DIR/cdk/Template/openerp-server
```

Also when I connect in SSH I don't find my template folder.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you give a link to the git repository (github manybe?) where your custom catridge code is?

Answer (score 1):

Openshift Origin has annoying timeout hardcoded in one gem of itself.

Find line 1006 in the following file:

> /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-console-1.26.3.1/app/models/rest_api/base.rb

The default timeout is set in the following line (line 1006):

> self.read_timeout = 240

Other timeouts can be setuped due to documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I have a working quickstart here: https://github.com/caruccio/openshift-openerp-quickstart/blob/master/README_en.md

You could use this code to your template dir. Please not it is "template", not "Template".